# Etross SMS Printer

Tags: printing, sms, gsm

All,
I ordered and received a Etroos SMS Printer from China and now that I have it I see the user manual is simply a joke!
I followed the user manual to send a sms to device and print something but I can't get it working, has anyone here used these devices?
The phone works, I can send SMS, it seems it does receive the SMS (I see lights are changing) but no printing, no order history and not even I can see the SMS in the history!

Any idea? Help is appreciated.

Amir

Answer (score 1):

In case you end up with the same issue, finally got it to work by upgrading the firmware and prn definitions using the latest utility from the manufacturer.

Contact them, they reply with huge delay, use paypal to pay and open a dispute if they didn't answer and they will get back to you!!!

Amir

Comment: Is this the one you have http://goo.gl/wWHvf? I'm having similar problems, I can make and receive calls, send sms but it doesn't seem to receive sms messages! Nothing happens when I send I send a message to it...

Can you tell me where you got the firmware upgrade from?

Comment: I need some manual or a driver... do you perhaps have any of those? I got nothing but the printer, no manual, nothing!

Comment: Yes I do have the driver and manual but we ended up not using this product due to so many other issues. We bought the original one. If you need more info email me and I can send you what I have and hope it works for you.

Comment: My email is filip@jarno.pl. Thanks for the help in advance!